# Parity Db Lock Error after Updating

Tags: parity

I just updated my Parity client on Mac to v1.5.0, but now get this error:

```
Client service error: Client(Database("IO error: lock /Users/<path>/.parity/906a34e69aec8c0d/v5.3-sec-overlayrecent/db/LOCK: Resource temporarily unavailable"))
```

Any ideas how to deal with this?

Comment: It's already running.

Answer (score 2):

It means that the node is already running.

If you used Mac installer it automatically runs Parity as a background service.
Just go to `http://localhost:8080` to see the UI.

If you prefer to run Parity manually either stop or uninstall the Service:

- To stop: `$ launchctl stop io.parity.ethereum`
- To uninstall: `$ sudo /usr/local/libexec/uninstall-parity.sh`

Details:
https://github.com/ethcore/parity/blob/master/mac/install-readme.txt